# Oracle TKPROF output

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

what are the main features to be look into TKPROF output.I mean how to interprete TKPROF output ?
What is the difference between CPU and ELAPSED ?

Answer (score 2):

You can read [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/sqltrace.htm#i4642) on Oracle documentation to know more about interpreting TKPROF output.

`CPU Time` is the time for which CPU was busy executing the task, or in other words, the time needed for actually executing the query.

`Elapsed Time` is the sum of CPU time and the wait time. Wait time is the time spent in waiting for resources, like waiting for I/O.

Comment: @user2090701:And `elapsed Time` is not much useful since other process also affect elapsed time . Adding to Incogito,you need to set your `TIME_STATISTICS to TRUE` ,otherwise trace file will be missing vital information.For `CPU time` ,it will be zero(parse phase) if stats were found in shared pool ,and one must read about recursive SQL